# what does "::" in user::rw- mean

Tags: linux, acl

When I see the permissions using the getfacl(). The permission information about the users on the files gets listed down.

```
# file: file.1
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:adm:r--
group::r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

I could not understand what the "user::rw-" mean .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines beginning with `user::`, `group::`, and `other::` are translations of the traditional Unix permission modes for the file's owner, group, and other, respectively, into ACL syntax. The lines with a user or group name after `user:` or `group:` are more specific ACLs for those named users and groups.

See [here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_getfacl.htm) for a more detailed explanation of how to interpret the output of `getfacl`

Comment: group::r--
mask::r--
other::r-- does this also mean the same as user::rw-

Comment: Sorry, my answer is wrong, I'll edit it.